# Randomizing Rails Root Path between two views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

Is there a way I can switch between to views at random for the root path?

```
root :to => 'pages#blue' or root :to => 'pages#red'
```

Thanks for any kind of help with this.

Comment: You can consider using some a/b testing gem. https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/A_B_Testing

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. I took a look at ABingo today, but seems like the existing solutions focus more on testing copy/text within the view rather that messing with the routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a lambda as the value of `:to`, so theoretically you could return two different responses randomly. It might be a better idea to swap the layout/view that's rendered though.

**Edit**

```
root to: lambda {|env| [ 302, {'Location'=> your_randomizing_code_here }, [] ]}
```

You could do that, or something very similar in your controller:

```
class YourRootController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    render some_method_that_returns_your_view_paths_randomly
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, would yo kind enough to provide an example how a function like that would look like. Since I understand what needs to be done, but have no idea how to lay it out.